# Increase SPI buffer size in Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I need to send 10 k bytes over SPI in single transfer (yes, because Linux is so realtime, if I send these bytes in two transfers, I do not match the timings of IC).

But maximum size of message in spi_bcm2708 kernel module is 4096 bytes. How do I modify this value (preferably without recompilation of the module)? If I can do with specifying parameter to the module, what parameter and in what file I need to specify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some time, the Pi Foundation have compiled the SPI device driver into the kernel. The way to change the buffer size now is to edit the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file and add:

```
spidev.bufsiz=<NEEDED BUFFER SIZE>
```

Comment: The current buffer size can be checked via `cat /sys/module/spidev/parameters/bufsiz`

Comment: Although spidev.bufsiz increases the buffer size, SPI is still limited to 4096 (under python 3.5)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/local.conf`:

```
options spidev bufsiz=<NEEDED BUFFER SIZE>
```

Comment: The current buffer size can be checked via `cat /sys/module/spidev/parameters/bufsiz`