# PyLepton_capture got [Errno 90] Message too long

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I have executed Pylepton_capture
https://github.com/groupgets/pylepton
But I got this error message
Environment: Raspberry Pi 4

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pylepton_capture", line 37, in <module>
    image = capture(flip_v = options.flip_v, device = options.device)
  File "./pylepton_capture", line 10, in capture
    a,_ = l.capture()
  File "/home/pi/pylepton/pylepton/Lepton.py", line 153, in capture
    Lepton.capture_segment(self.__handle, self.__xmit_buf, self.__msg_size, self.__capture_buf[0])
  File "/home/pi/pylepton/pylepton/Lepton.py", line 125, in capture_segment
    ret = ioctl(handle, iow, xs_buf[xs_size * (60 - messages):], True)
IOError: [Errno 90] Message too long
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess your problems comes from using Lepton 3.x, which takes lager resolution images than Lepton 2.x (160x120 vs 80x60)

If so, first you have to use the git branch for this model, either [lepton3](https://github.com/groupgets/pylepton/tree/lepton3) or [lepton3-dev](https://github.com/groupgets/pylepton/tree/lepton3-dev) (which are in Python2)

If the problem continues, maybe you have to increase the SPI buffer size to manage such big images (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427996/increase-spi-buffer-size-in-raspbian/16440226)):

Edit `/boot/cmdline.txt` and add in the end:

```
spidev.bufsiz=65535
```

Then reboot your raspberry and check it worked with:

```
cat /sys/module/spidev/parameters/bufsiz
```

I hope this works for you

**EDIT:**

Check the [related Github issue](https://github.com/groupgets/pylepton/issues/52). Other solutios like increasing the `Lepton.SPIDEV_MESSAGE_LIMIT` value may help also